# Css Height problem in Chrome

Tags: css, properties, height

i am not able to set the height of the Div of this theme to 156px;

Its inheriting css property from some place else and making it 118px

[image]

Please the following website in Chrome and firefox you will see the difference

http://jssamch.com/

Comment: Why not find out where it's inheriting it from using the document inspector, and remove/overwrite the rule?

Comment: @Pekka i am trying to debug. see my comment on the answer. i am not able to locate height:118px in my code :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's coming from `1-default.css`, line 19.

Remove the `height: 118px` property.

You should really be using Firebug (for Firefox) or Developer Tools (for Chrome) to figure out this sort of issue on your own.

Comment: #header { background:url(images/header.png) no-repeat;
width:968px;
height: 150px;
} thats my line number 19 in that file :(

Comment: Then you should ensure you have uploaded the correct file to the correct location, and clear your browser's cache. I'm looking at it right now, and http://jssamch.com/wp-content/themes/v3/v3/skins/1-default.css contains `#header { background:url(1-default/header.png) no-repeat; width:968px; height: 118px; margin: 10px auto 0 auto; }`.

Comment: @Harsha nope, I get `118px`, too. http://jssamch.com/wp-content/themes/v3/v3/skins/1-default.css